# How to compare column values/rows in same table

Tags: sql

[image]

It should pull the count of users_id where for the firstname/lastname of users is different for each of the user id.

here it should result 2 records( 1 & 7).

Comment: Table details are in the hyper link, Pls let me know if anyone has come across such scenario to pull the records.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: No link, please. Add sample table data and the expected result as properly formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt. BTW, are you using MySQL or DB2?

Comment: What if firstname values are same but lastname values are different ? Will that still be considered a different row ?

Comment: Mysql and db2 are two different products with different syntax and features. Therefore I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you really use.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having count(*) = count(distinct firstname) and
       count(*) = count(distinct lastname);
```

I'm not sure if you want the names as pair.  If so:

```
having count(*) = count(distinct firstname, lastname)
```

Not all databases support multiple arguments to `count(distinct)`.  If this is what you really intend, it is easy enough to phrase without using this.

Comment: Nice approach - I only can hardly imagine he does not want the the name as pair. In Db2 (LUW) the  count(distinct firstname, lastname) needs to be changed to count(distinct firstname || lastname) I think

Answer (score 0):

```
 select user_id,count(*)
 from table 
 group by user_id having 
 count(distinct firstname) =count(firstname) and count(distinct 
 lastname)=count(lastname) ;
```

> This gives those userids where on grouping userids if distinct fname and lname are greater than 1 for each userid group that means that group contains no duplicates.

Comment: Sorry but your statement will not work if an additional row with sample data (8,7, 'will', 'Rj') would be added.

Answer (score 0):

Following SQL will work - it will also work if you would add lets say this row to your sample data (8,7, 'will', 'Rj') making User_id 7 having 4 rows but two of them with identical names.

```
with temp as (
SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname 
     , count(*) over (partition by user_id, firstname, lastname) as counter
 FROM t2
) 
SELECT * --distinct user_id
FROM temp t
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM temp WHEE counter = 2 and user_id = t.user_id)
```

The statements returns all rows with names unless you change the * to the commented distinct user_id then it will only return the user_id having ONLY unique names.